# .addClass not working with radios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn JS/JQuery so I wrote this little quiz app. I want to highlight the wrong answer and correct answer when the user clicks submit, but it's not working.

Here's the functions:

```
function correctAnswer () {
    var answer = questions[questionNumber].correct;
    console.log("answer =" + answer)
    $("#radio" + answer + "+ label").addClass(".correctAnswer");
    questionNumber++
 };

 function wrongAnswer () {
    var answer = questions[questionNumber].correct;
    var userAnswer = $(".list input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    if (answer != userAnswer) {
        $(".list input[type=radio]:checked" + "+ label").addClass(".wrongAnswer");
    }
    questionNumber++
 };
```

Here's the CSS:

```
input[type=radio] + label {
    font-family: Helvetica;
color:#FFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center; 
border-style: none;
background: #4592FF;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width:100%;
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label { 
background-image: none;
background-color:#1646B5;
}
.correctAnswer {
font-family: Helvetica;
color:#FFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center; 
border-style: none;
    background: #4592FF;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width:100%;
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
.wrongAnswer {
font-family: Helvetica;
color:#FFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center; 
border-style: none;
    margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width:100%;
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
background:#FF4B19;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio0" name="radios" value="all">
                    <label for="radio0"></label>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios"value="false">
                    <label for="radio1"></label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="true">
                    <label for="radio2"></label> 
                </li>   
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
                    <label for="radio3"></label> 
                </li>
            </ul>
```

All of the quiz data (questions/possible answers/correct answer) are stored in an array.

Sorry about the indentation of the CSS. I don't know why it's displaying that way

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle if interested. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=rP95pwLxKi

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide only class name i.e. *correctAnswer*. You don't need to prefix it with `.`

Use

```
$("#radio" + answer + "+ label").addClass("correctAnswer");
```

instead of

```
$("#radio" + answer + "+ label").addClass(".correctAnswer");
```

Similarly use `removeClass("wrongAnswer");`

Comment: Thanks @Satpal. I made the change, but it's still not working.

Comment: @Chad, Is your selector correct. I am guessing it should be `$("#radio" + answer + " label")`

Comment: the selector is correct. I need $("#radio" + answer + " +label") because that gives me the correct label.